# Material Sidenav content doesnt show main content. How can I create main layout sit under the navigation?

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

Sorry, I am a newbie with angular, and not able to get the main layout sit under the navigation header. It shows the menu with the fixed height(Which I can adjust inline), but doesnt show full menu. If I adjust the height to 100vh, it pushes the main content under it.

Is it a good structure? If not, can you please suggest the improvements?

header.component.html

```
<div style="height:10vh;">
  <mat-toolbar class="header-bg">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm>
        <mat-icon style="color:#fff;">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span style="color:white;">MainWeb</span>
      <span class="menu-spacer"></span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <!-- <a (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item><mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="home"></mat-icon></a> -->
        <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              Menu 1
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-nav-list>
              <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">1.1</a>
              <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">1.2</a>
              <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">1.3</a>
          </mat-nav-list>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
          <a href="#" mat-list-item>Menu 2</a>
          <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              Menu 2
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">2.1</a>
              </mat-nav-list>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            Menu 3
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">3.1</a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel [class.mat-elevation-z0]="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          Menu 4
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-nav-list>
              <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">4.1</a>
              <a mat-list-item routerLink="#">4.2</a>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-expansion-panel>      
      </mat-nav-list> 
    </mat-sidenav>
    
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill="200">
      <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md class="nav-web-group">
        <!-- The following menu items will be hidden on both SM and XS screen sizes -->
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon iconPositionEnd>expand_more</mat-icon>WHome</button>
              <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>1.1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>1.2</button>
              </mat-menu>
          <a href="#" mat-button>Menu 2</a>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon iconPositionEnd>expand_more</mat-icon>Menu 3</button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>3.1</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>3.2</button>
          </mat-menu>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon iconPositionEnd>expand_more</mat-icon>Menu 4</button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item><mat-icon iconPositionEnd>expand_more</mat-icon>4.1</button>
          </mat-menu>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon iconPositionEnd>expand_more</mat-icon>Menu 5</button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button mat-menu-item>5.1</button>
          </mat-menu>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

header.componet.css

```
.hamburger {
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
}

.example-icon {
    padding: 0 14px;
  }
  
  .example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .menu-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .mat-icon {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #000000;
  }
  
  .image-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .header-bg {
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(180, 7%, 3%, 1) 0%, hsla(186, 66%, 9%, 1) 100%);
  } 

.app-sidenav {
    width: 230px;
}
.app-sidenav-content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
} 

.app-sidenav-content a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-web-group {
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:3em;
  margin-bottom:-20em !important;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nav-web-group:hover {
  background: none !important;
}

.nav-web-group button, a {
  color:#000;
  text-align:left;
  padding-right:1em;
  padding-left:1em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12 px !important;
}

::ng-deep .custom-submenu {
  .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  }
  .mat-mdc-menu-item {
    color: #ffaf02;
    background: none !important;
    min-height: 40px;
  }
  .mat-drawer {
    position: fixed !important;
    margin-top: 65px;
  }
}

  ::ng-deep .custom-submenu button:hover {
  .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  color: #ffaf02;
  background-color: none !important;
  }
  .mat-mdc-button {
    background: none !important;
  }}
  
  ::ng-deep .custom-sidenav {
  .mat-sidenav {
    position: fixed !important;
    margin-top: 65px;
    z-index: 999999999 !important;
  }
  .mat-drawer-container {
    display: contents;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .mat-sidenav {
    display: none;
  }
}
  .mat-sidenav-container {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 65px;
    z-index: 999999999 !important;
  }
  .mat-drawer-backdrop {
    position: contents;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  }
```

login.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlex="17" fxFlex.sm="10" fxFlex.xs="10">
    <div fxFlex="80" fxFlex.sm="100" fxFlex.xs="100"></div>
  </div>

  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlex="83" fxFlex.sm="90" fxFlex.xs="90">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlex="80" fxFlex.sm="170" fxFlex.xs="70">
      <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.sm="70" fxFlex.xs="70">
        <div class="login-wrapper" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <mat-card class="box" fxFlex="300" fxFill fxLayoutGap>
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>Log in</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <form class="example-form">
              <mat-card-content>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Username">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Password">
                </mat-form-field>
              </mat-card-content>
              <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" class="btn-block">Log in</button>
            </form>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="30" fxFlex.sm="30" fxFlex.xs="30"></div>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="row" fxFlex="20" fxFlex.sm="30" fxFlex.xs="20">
      <div fxFlex="30" fxFlex.sm="70" fxFlex.xs="50"></div>
      <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.sm="30" fxFlex.xs="50"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Please feel to ask for any more details, as I am unsure what all code to provide for this fix.

Many thanks
BN